# How to get a specific column value from a DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

How to get a specific column value from a DataTable in c#

I have a problem with my code **C#**.

I need read a specific column value from a **DataTable**.

I've tried using this solution without success, because the output is the name of column selected in the query *(File)* and not the value of field database.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Here is my code:

```
public DataTable GridViewBind()
{
    using (OdbcConnection cn =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
    {    
        sql1 = " SELECT FILE FROM tbl_A WHERE Id = 1; ";


        using (OdbcDataAdapter command =
            new OdbcDataAdapter(sql1, cn))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();

                dset = new DataSet();
                dset.Clear();
                command.Fill(dset);
                DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;                    
                GridView1.DataBind();

                Response.Write(dt.Columns[0].ToString());

                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (command != null)
                {
                    command.Dispose();
                }

                if (cn != null)
                {
                    cn.Close();
                    cn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit #1**

Now I have error:

**System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.**

```
public DataTable GridViewBind()
{
    using (OdbcConnection cn =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
    {    
        sql1 = " SELECT FILE FROM tbl_A WHERE Id = 1; ";


        using (OdbcDataAdapter command =
            new OdbcDataAdapter(sql1, cn))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();

                dset = new DataSet();
                dset.Clear();
                command.Fill(dset);
                DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;                    
                GridView1.DataBind();

                string file = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
                Response.Write(file.ToString());  

                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (command != null)
                {
                    command.Dispose();
                }

                if (cn != null)
                {
                    cn.Close();
                    cn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What makes which column's value specific?  The table normally contains multiple rows. Use a loop and use `row.Field<string>(0)` to access the value of each row.

Comment: I need read the value of column **File** selected in the query **sql1**.

Comment: Maybe help this: if ( dt.Columns[ 0 ].ColumnName == "columnName" )
                {
                    gridview1.DataSource = dt;
                    gridview1.DataBind( );
                }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The table normally contains multiple rows. Use a loop and use `row.Field<string>(0)` to access the value of each row.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string file = row.Field<string>("File");
}
```

You can also access it via index:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string file = row.Field<string>(0);
}
```

If you expect only one row, you can also use the indexer of `DataRowCollection`:

```
string file = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
```

Since this fails if the table is empty, use `dt.Rows.Count` to check if there is a row:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    file = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
```

Comment: @Hamamelis: i have mentioned that already in a comment in my answer(_"fails if the table is empty..."_). I've edited now my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I know its too late. . but what if I want only datatable headers and that to specific datatable column headers?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to achieve. From the `DataTable`, first we can apply the `Select` function to get only the row that is associated with `Id=1`.

After that, we can do the `CopyToDataTable()` function so as to get it in the `DataTable` format.

Since, we are expecting that there is only row for `Id=1`, we can directly apply `Rows[0]` and then give the column name, convert to string and assign to `file` variable.

```
string file = dt.Select("Id=1").CopyToDataTable().Rows[0]["FILE"].ToString()
```

Note that if you are selecting string value, you need to apply single quotes. For eg, if `Id` is of string type, then you need to apply like below.

```
Id='1'
```